# Need to perform calculations on array within Object array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of 15 Student objects that consist of an int (student ID) and an array (scores for 5 lab assignments). I am required to calculate the Low, High, and Avg scores for each of the 5 labs. The only way I can think of doing this is looking at all the arrays by columns, but my arrays are a row for each student. How would I go about doing these calculations on these arrays. 
Included is a Util class which the Student object array comes from and a Student class to define the object. I only need help with the Statistics class provided.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Util.class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Util {
   public static Student[] readFile(String fileName) {
         Student studentArray[]=new Student[15];
         try{
            FileReader file = new FileReader("studentData.txt");
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(file);
            String line;
            line = buff.readLine();
            int index=0;
            while(line != null){
               System.out.println(line);
               if(index>14){
                  break;
               }
               line = buff.readLine();
               String[] result = line.split("\\s");
               int sid = Integer.parseInt(result[0]);
               int scores[] = new int[5];
               for(int x=1;x<result.length;x++){
                  scores[x-1] = Integer.parseInt(result[x]);
               }
               Student myCSC20Student = new Student(sid, scores);
               studentArray[index++] = myCSC20Student;
            }
         }
         catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
         } 
         return studentArray;  
      }    
   }
```

Student.class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Student {
   final int LABS = 5;
   private int SID;
   private int scores[] = new int[LABS];   


   public Student(int sid, int[] scores)
    {
      this.SID=sid;
      this.scores = scores;
    }

   //getters and setters for SID and scores
   public int getID() {
      return SID;
   }
   public void setID(int x) {
      this.SID = x;
   }
   public int[] getScore() {
      return scores;
   }  
}
```

Statistics.class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Statistics {
   final int LABS = 5;
   public int[] lowscores = new int[LABS];
   private int[] highscores = new int[LABS];
   private float[] avgscores = new float[LABS];
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   Student[] studArr = Util.readFile("studentData.txt");

   System.out.println("");

   for(int i=0; i<=studArr.length-1; i++){
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studArr[i].getScore()));
   }

   }

   void calculateLow(Student[] a){

   }
   void calculateHigh(Student[] a){

   }
   void calculateAvg(Student[] a){

   }
}
```

Output Class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Output{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Student[] studArr = Util.readFile("studentData.txt");
      Statistics statistics = new Statistics();
      statistics.calculateLow(studArr);
      statistics.calculateHigh(studArr);
      statistics.calculateAvg(studArr);
      System.out.println("Low scores:");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(statistics.getLowscores()));
      System.out.println("High scores:");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(statistics.getHighscores()));
      System.out.println("Average scores:");
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(statistics.getAvgscores()));
   }

}
```

[Output of scores of all 15 students for the 5 labs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITgs4.png)

Comment: Can you modify the `Student` class? If so, I'd add methods for `getLowScore()`, `getHighScore` and `getTotalScore`, and allow that class to do the bulk of the work. Then in your `Statistics` class you wouldn't need to iterate the `int[]` from `getScore()` (really should probably be `getScores()` as it is returning multiple values). Otherwise, you iterate the `Student[]` array, get the `int[]` and do the calculations. If I understood your question correctly.

Comment: What Kevin suggests would work but seems a bit odd to push some of the statistical calculation into the Student class.  Separation of concerns seems to indicate it should be all in the Statistics class.  My problem is you evidently have done no work at all in your Statistics class.  Please make an effort for at least one of those methods.  You have an array of Students, and each Student contains an array of tests.  Surely you know how to nest `for` loops...

Comment: @KevinO Hello. I'm not sure how I would write any methods at all if I can't separate the scores of each lab. Could you tell me how I can view look at each lab column individually.

Comment: @markspace, I certainly respect your position, and the separation of concerns is something to keep in mind. I simply take the position that if a student knows about his/her lab scores, it makes sense to be able to ask 'what was your highest lab score?'. Modeling that leads to the three methods I suggested. Nonetheless, you are correct that only providing the raw scores is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Statistics {
    final int LABS = 5;
    public int[] lowscores = new int[LABS];
    private int[] highscores = new int[LABS];
    private float[] avgscores = new float[LABS];
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student[] studArr = Util.readFile("studentData.txt");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<=studArr.length-1; i++){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(studArr[i].getScore()));
        }
        Statistics statistics = new Statistics();
        statistics.calculateLow(studArr);
        statistics.calculateHigh(studArr);
        statistics.calculateAvg(studArr);
        System.out.println("Low scores:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(statistics.getLowscores()));
        System.out.println("High scores:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(statistics.getHighscores()));
        System.out.println("Average scores:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(statistics.getAvgscores()));

    }

    public void calculateLow(Student[] a){
        for (int i = 0; i < LABS; i++) {
            final int lab = i;
            lowscores[lab] = Arrays.stream(a)
                    .mapToInt(student -> student.getScore()[lab])
                    .min()
                    .orElse(0);
        }
    }
    public void calculateHigh(Student[] a){
        for (int i = 0; i < LABS; i++) {
            final int lab = i;
            highscores[lab] = Arrays.stream(a)
                    .mapToInt(student -> student.getScore()[lab])
                    .max()
                    .orElse(0);
        }
    }
    public void calculateAvg(Student[] a){
        for (int i = 0; i < LABS; i++) {
            final int lab = i;
            avgscores[lab] = (float) Arrays.stream(a)
                    .mapToInt(student -> student.getScore()[lab])
                    .average()
                    .orElse(0);
        }
    }

    public int[] getLowscores() {
        return lowscores;
    }

    public int[] getHighscores() {
        return highscores;
    }

    public float[] getAvgscores() {
        return avgscores;
    }
}
```

Comment: A reasonable solution, assuming the OP can use streams. I think some explanation as to how the code works, rather than just the solution, would be useful for others who might find this page.

Comment: Hello, when I try to run one of these methods, I get "error: non-static method calculateLow(Student[]) cannot be referenced from a static context". If I start adding static to things, everything messes up, any ideas?

Comment: You need an object to run non-static methods. Like `Statistics statistics = new Statistics();` You main method is static, so you can't call non-static methods from it without objects. It doesn't have `this` reference.

Comment: Then you can call methods, using the object. `statistics.calculateLow(studentArray);`

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk Okay, I made the Statistics object and called the method. But how would I print out all the values?

Comment: Your values also non-static so you need to get them from object. I would recommend create getters `public int[] getLowscores() {
        return lowscores;
    }` and use them `statistics.getLowscores()`

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk I'm not very familiar with array streams. Could you explain to me how I would write the getter and setter methods for them?

Comment: You don't need setters, because you calculate values. How to write a getter I demonstrated in previous comment. Just copy the code.

Comment: @BogdanLukiyanchuk Okay I made them all getters. My calculateLow() works but my calculateHigh and calculateAvg run into a "NoSuchMethodError". Also, in the statistics class, it says that float[] cannot be converted to int[] in calculateAvg.

Comment: @AlanNavai I edited the answer to show how you can use it.

Comment: If your output class in another package then you need to make calculating classes `public`

Answer (score 0):

@Bogdan-Lukiyanchuk provided a solution that utilizes Java streams. I am of the impression the assignment is designed to only use loops and arrays. As such, a pointer to the solution is something along the lines of:

```
void calculateLow(Student[] a) {
  // if we don't have any students, then just leave
  if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // set to the maximum score one could possibly have
  int lowScore = Integer.MAX_INT;
  Student lowPersonOnTotem = null;

  // process all of the students
  for (Student student : a) {
    int[] scores = student.getScore();

    // loop over all of the scores; if the score is lower than any 
    // previous, update the lowScore and who had it
    for (int score : scores) {
      if (score < lowScore) {
        lowScore = score;
        lowPersonOnTotem = student;
      }
    }
  }

   System.out.printf("Lowest score of all students is %d achieved by %d\n",
      lowScore, lowPersonOnTotem.getId());
}
```

Now, following from the critique by @markspace in the comments, I would think having `calculateLow()` return a value and then have the display elsewhere would be most appropriate, but the method was marked as `void` in the OP's example.

The other methods are essentially the same loop, but the math changes.